# "using typedef-name ... as class" on a forward declaration

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, typedef, forward-declaration

I'm doing some policy-based designs here and I have the need to typedef lots of template types to shorten the names.
Now the problem comes that when I need to use a pointer to one of those types I try to just forward-declare it but the compiler complains with a `test.cpp:8: error: using typedef-name ‘Test1’ after ‘class’`

It's nothing to do with sizes as I don't need the obj at all, its just a pointer in a ".h" file where I don't want to bring the whole template in.
This is g++:

```
//Works
class Test{};
class Test;

//Doesn't work
class Test{};
typedef Test Test1;
class Test1;
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's correct. A typedef-name cannot be used in such a forward declaration (this is technically called an elaborated type specifier, and if such a specifier resolves to a typedef-name, the program is ill-formed).

I don't understand why you actually *need* the forward declaration in the first place. Because if you already have the typedef in place, why not just use that typedef? It's just aswell denoting that class.

**Edit**: From your comment, it seems you need a designated forward declaration header, much in the same vain of `<iosfwd>`. So, if you template is called `Test_Template_Name_Long`, this a header can look like

***TestFwd.h***

```
template<typename A, typename B> 
class Test_Template_Name_Long;

typedef Test_Template_Name_Long<int, bool> Test1;
```

Then you can just use that header, instead of doing `class Test1`, which the compiler has no clue about what it is (and will think it is a new class, independent of any template and typedef).

Comment: Tried to upvote you because you beat me but I'm out of votes for today :(

Comment: well, the problem comes in a .cpp file that includes this seconday .h file and the original one with the typedef.

I need the forward declaration because I need to declare a pointer to that class and want to avoid including the template file(with the typedef in).

So there is no solution for such a thing?

Comment: Then you have to forward-declare the class and the typedef in the file explicitly. Remember that between files typedef'd names do not exist -- the compiler expands them into their untypedefed names at compile time. If you simply forward declare the typedef'd name later then it will fail at link time because after compilation no such name should exist.

Comment: Great! Thanks for that last edit!! I think that matches my requirements.

Comment: I have a project that mixes C and C++. The C headers have lots of `typedef` but I can't just include them ahead of my C++ headers because it generates a bunch of errors. Things are becoming tricky as the project grows and I wonder if it is a good practicy to avoid them. As this is in a related context, could anyone geve me a clue?

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef Test Test1;
class Test1;
```

fails because the `typedef` statement serves as the declaration for the Test1 type.

Basically, when the compiler sees the typedef, it remembers that Test1 is a synonym for Test. Then when it sees `class Test1;`, it thinks there's a new type you are declaring. But it can't treat that as a declaration because the name Test1 is already being used by the typedef.

If you want to use a forward declaration for Test1, for example, you have to put the typedef in each file using that typedef as a forward declaration. Therefore, instead of `class Test1;`, you'd do:

```
class Test;
typedef Test Test1;
```

Answer (score 2):

One more case in which this situation arises is this:

```
// File: network_fwd.hpp
#ifndef __NETWORK_FWD_HPP__
#define __NETWORK_FWD_HPP__
class Network;
typedef Network GarnetNetwork;
#endif // __NETWORK_FWD_HPP__

// File: network.hpp
#include "network_fwd.hpp"

class GarnetIntLink : public BasicLink
{
  public:

    friend class GarnetNetwork;

};
```

I had to do that because there was actually a class called GarnetNetwork that I merged into class Network, and I wanted to propagate that throughout the rest of the code using that typedef.
GCC still gives this message: **error: using typedef-name ‘GarnetNetwork’ after ‘class’**.

I really appreciate your help about this case.

NB: By the way I posted this question here because I thought it is pretty much the same thing and in order not to distract the community.